# c# async await task : cannot await 'void'

Tags: c#, async-await

I've been using Xabe.FFmpeg for a project. Tasks, async and await are new to me but I've been learning.
I trying do a basic conversion with Xabe.FFmpeg. I get an error that says "cannot await 'void'".

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task Run()
    {
        string inputFileName = @"C:\Users\npsie\Videos\Sample.mkv";
        string outputFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(inputFileName, ".mp4");
        await FFmpeg.FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.ToMp4(inputFileName, outputFileName).Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `FormMain_Load` should probably be `async void` and then you should await `Run` instead of using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to `await` the call to `.Start()` on the `Task` returned by `ToMp4()`.  Remove that call to `Start()` and await the returned `Task` itself:

```
await FFmpeg.FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.ToMp4(inputFileName, outputFileName);
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but looking at the [docs](https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/docs.html), Start() is awaitable.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: Those docs seem a bit light on details.  Where is the documentation for `.ToMp4()`?  If it returns a `Task` then `.Start()` is [not awaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start).  It's also possible and not unprecedented for library documentation to have errors.

Comment: @user3646458 you might have some success in calling it inside `Task.Run()`. The library may have missed a `ConfigureAwait(false)`